# where to put conditional in chain of operations

Tags: programming-practices

I have two types of input data which will go through a number of steps for processing. The processing differs only in one of those steps, e.g.:

TypeX: A() -> B() -> Cx() -> D()

TypeY: A() -> B() -> Cy() -> D()

What's a good way to approach structuring this type of code? For example, I could branch right at the start:

```
def main
  if(d is type X) process_type_X() else process_type_Y()

def process_type_X(x)
  D(Cx(B(A(x))))

def process_type_Y(y)
  D(Cy(B(A(x))))
```

Or at the specific step

```
def process_data(d)
   d1 = A(d)
   d2 = B(d1)
   d3 = if (d is type X) Cx(d2) else Cy(d2)
   D(d3)
```

It seems like the first way is clearer, it indicates these are two different types of data and are processed differently up front. On the other hand, I imagine if the function calls were more nested and the difference was in some small leaf function, you'd have a lot of duplication.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your second example contains duplicated code. You can remove it like this:

```py
def process_data(d)
   C = (if d is type X) Cx else Cy
   d1 = A(d)
   d2 = B(d1)
   d3 = C(d2)
   D(d3)
```

However, given the condition `if d is type X`, it seems like the condition itself should move to the actual type. That is, if you need to use `Cx` if `d` is of type `X`, and `Cy` if `d` is of type `Y`, then `Cx` and `Cy` are likely to belong to the actual `X` and `Y` classes.

Your code therefore becomes:

```py
def process_data(d)
   d1 = A(d)
   d2 = B(d1)
   d3 = d.C(d2)
   D(d3)
```

which is much more readable.

Comment: Basically you need object-oriented polymorphism. On a related note, you can accomplish this in a functional language using `def process_data(d, c)` where `c` is a function pointer or reference. The caller determines which specific implementation of `c` is needed (i.e. Cx or Cy).

Comment: Sorry about the delay and thanks for answering. In my particular case I don't think I have the option of actually representing the different data with different types (without huge refactoring on a codebase I'm new to), although I agree that generally makes sense for this problem.